# Supporting OpenGL Screen Capture by Third Party Applications

Tags: opengl, screen-capture

I am trying to record a gameplay video for an OpenGL game I am creating.  I am able to capture the 3D scene graphics (which are rendered to a custom framebuffer) but am not able to capture the GUI graphics (which are rendered to the default backbuffer).

This behavior is the same with OBS, Bandicam, and FRAPS (All on Windows), regardless of whether the game is running fullscreen or windowed. Toggling overlay capture doesn't change the behavior.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 1):

A standard requirement for an OpenGL application to support screen capture is to ensure that the read framebuffer is pointing to the backbuffer before swapping buffers.  The code for this is:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Screen capture software uses the active framebuffer for reading, and ideally that software should not alter framebuffer state and instead assume that the target application already has the read framebuffer set to the desired capture buffer when swapping buffers.

If the read framebuffer is not set to the back buffer on swap, an intermediate image will be captured instead of the final image.

This requirement is specific to screen capture and overlay injection but is not otherwise a requirement for normal rendering, since framebuffer state does not affect buffer swapping and a render pipeline may never need to read from the back buffer.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why they can't switch the framebuffer manually, and then restore the original one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Third party applications could change the framebuffer, but ideally they should be as unobtrusive as possible, especially when multiple applications are injecting into the same rendering process.  OpenGL uses a single threaded model, but it doesn't prevent all race conditions.

Comment: What race conditions could there be?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Screen capture programs ususally hook into the buffer swap function (`glXSwapBuffers`, `wglSwapBuffers` and such). Notably this function is *not* part of OpenGL and also not tied to OpenGL context(s). So between the last OpenGL function call (like setting the read framrbuffer with `glBindFramebuffer`) and the call of the buffer swap function, the OpenGL context may have been transferred to a different thread and state changed there. It's very unlikely, and due to the obscurity of how OpenGL contexts work I'd wager no program does it. But it's a possibility.